# Aside from Segues, how can I get from one view to another view in iOS if I am using story boards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I am currently using StoryBoards and I was wondering what are my options to go from one ViewController to another.

I am familiar with Segues and I know you can assign identifiers on them.

Is there an alternative way? (I am asking for the sake of learning).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using storyboards then you should probably use segues. Otherwise you're kind of missing out on the benefits of storyboards. However you can build custom segues and even if you're using storyboards you can still add your on views programatically and animate views on and off screen as you see fit.

So the brief answer to your questions is you can use whatever you want to animate views on and off screen, if your really want to role your own navigation type controller go ahead - it's probably a nice thing to do for learning purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [presentViewController:animated:completion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a).

It will always show the view as a modal view. But you can also use Segues programmatically, and it is the recommended way to make transition between view controllers.